# Exploding Connected Shapes

Tags: polygons

I have recently been tasked with creating an 'exploded' view for what amounts to a collection of shapes in a 2d coordinate plane. These shapes are all touching in some way. What I need to do is translate all of the coordinates of these shapes in such a way that I create gaps in between them with aesthetically pleasing gaps.

As stated before, I have a list of all of the line segments / arcs that make up these shapes. I've spent some time looking around on google, but honestly I think I lack the vocabulary for that to be effective. I'm not exactly a mathematician, and this might not be the right stack exchange for this so I expect this to be difficult. I'm merely seeking guidance here, not necessarily a solution. Any help here would be appreciated.

Say I start with this:

[image]

For reasons which are probably irrelevant, I need to group a set of these shapes together such that what I'll end up dealing with is this:

[image]

In this case I would end up with something like this:

[image]

However, the possible combinations of these shapes is vast, and I can end up with something more complicated like this:

[image]

Where I would end up with something like:

[image]

Note in the last example I didn't remove the lines for the shapes I grouped together, but fundamentally it's the same idea as the first example. The ones still touching are logically grouped, so I would imagine that I can treat them as a single shape. You can see from this that the configuration can get complex quickly. Perhaps I'm overthinking the issue, but this is the idea.

Comment: Pick a central point and translate each polygon proportionately to how far away it is from the center.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I'm not convinced it will be that simple, but perhaps it is. The nature of the polygons is such that it can create convex/concave polygons which might create interlocking shapes... if you follow me there.

Comment: Pick a central point in each polygon and calculate their new positions ... then recalculate each point of the original polygon relative to its new center. ... Should be a doddle ?

Comment: "These polygons are all touching in some way": what do you mean ?

Comment: "line segments / arcs": so they aren't polygons ??

Comment: I agree with @DonaldSplutterwit.  For your edification, such a transformation is called a *homothety* ("ho MOTH a tee") and the point you pick is called the "homothetic center." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I love links. Much appreciated.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I suppose they wouldn't be with the arcs, 'shapes' if you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one suggestion that may work if the polygons are convex (1): scale the whole figure by some (small) factor of increase - perhaps $10\%$, so $1.1$. The polygons will still touch one another. Now shrink each polygon "in place" by a factor of $0.9$, using a center chosen inside each (perhaps the centroid). Then the polygons will be the same size as in the original, but spread out.

You can adjust the stretch/shrink factor to meet your aesthetic goals.

Consider editing the question to show us a picture of what you start with and what you might be pleased to end up with.

(1) The comment saying they may not be convex means this method might not work. All the more reason to show us a picture or two of what you need.

Comment: I can guarantee that the hull of the collection of polygons will be convex, I cannot however guarantee that the individual polygons will be. I can attach some pictures sure.

Comment: This is the same proposal as DonaldSplutterwit's.

Comment: I have provided some crude drawings.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Essentially, yes. I was writing it while he was writing his comment.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I'll begin implementing this. I appreciate the help and guidance guys!

Comment: Maybe it is possible to build a "repelling algorithm" where each piece repells its neighbours with a certain activity threshold...

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not always possible with concave polygons. A simple example:

[image]

Comment: I had not considered this.

Comment: After considering this, I don't actually think something like this would be possible given the constraints of how the configurations are made. I can end up with a convex shape like an L possibly... but I'm beginning to doubt that I'll en up with something like the shape above. I think that the Homothetic translation is the way to go.

Comment: @MarkW: this is why we needed more info about those "shapes".